# Java: make subclass be comparable only with the same subclass

Tags: java, subclass, comparable

I have an abstract Dice class and there are some concrete subclasses like SixFacesDice, TwentyFacesDice, etc... I want every Dice object to be comparable with an other but only if it is of the same subclass (e.g. a SixFacesDice can't be compared with a TwentyFacesDice) but I wouldn't to implement Comparable for every subclass.

The only way I see is to implement Comparable with Dice class and check if objects are of the same class, otherwise return 0. But this method is not elegant at all... Is there some method or design pattern to solve this?

Comment: Why do you say this is "not elegant at all"?

Comment: this is the right way to do it. Not only this ensures that your way of comparing dice is enforced by who every uses a dice to compare it with another dice but also your way on comparing cannot be changed as long as they use use your Dice superclass based subclass. Ofcourse you need to make the compare method final so that it cannot be oevrridden. Alternately you can look at implementing a comparable but that wont actually enforce anything.

Comment: I suspect the OP wants *compile-time* safety rather than just execution-time safety.

Comment: Because allaw different types of Dice to to compared... But, on the other hand, leaves different type dices not ordered at all. Then, yes, is not so bad :)

Comment: What does this comparison actually mean? How is one 6-sided die greater than or less than another?

Comment: Simply if you have 2 6-sided dice a and b, a is greater if the actual value is greater than the actual value of b.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you want *compile-time* safety rather than just *execution-time* safety, you could use generics, like this:

```
abstract class Dice<T extends Dice> implements Comparable<T> {
    int value;

    public int compareTo(T other) {
        return Integer.compare(value, other.value);
    }
}

final class Dice1 extends Dice<Dice1> {
}

final class Dice2 extends Dice<Dice2> {
}
```

That wouldn't stop someone from abusing it like this:

```
class BadDice extends Dice<Dice1>
```

... but when used properly, I think it gives you the behaviour you want.

Note that this only works with one inheritance level, too - you wouldn't be able to cleanly have a subclass of a subclass of `Dice<T>`, because then your "same class" enforcement would fail.

If you're fine with just execution-time safety, then comparing `this.getClass()` with `other.getClass()` is absolutely reasonable.

Comment: OP will probably have a `Collection<Dice>` which will contain heterogeneous dice instances. I don't think Generics can help.

Comment: @Jon Skeet Yes you're right. But I discared this way because I need more than one level in inheritance...

Comment: @user2691583: If you've thought of approaches and discarded them, you should state that in the question to avoid wasting people's time.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik: Unfortunately we don't really have enough context to know that... the OP's comments suggests they *do* want compile-time safety, but it's all a bit vague.

Comment: "otherwise return 0"---that, in my eyes, implies runtime checking.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik: Yes, but that's the approach the OP *doesn't* want to take. We could really do with more information from the OP though.

Comment: @Jon Skeet I'm not an expert and I didn't know if there were methods to use generics and got more than the first level of inherintance. You have confirmed that, thanks

Answer (score 2):

Elegant or not, comparing the result of `getClass()` is standard practice. *Except* that you shouldn't return 0 but instead throw a `ClassCastException`. Returning 0 does not signal "not comparable", but "equal", and that relation has certain constraints you cannot meet with that design, such as *transitivity*:

```
DiceA aLow, aHigh;
DiceB b;
```

In your case,

```
aLow.compareTo(b) == b.compareTo(aHigh) == 0
```

but

```
aLow.compareTo(aHigh) < 0
```